# Which context to use for Toast in Android?

Tags: android, android-context, android-toast

I just learned that I can use either:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.some_string,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

or,

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.some_string,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

To display a Toast in Android.

Earlier I thought context was actually a sort of handle to the parent window where it should be display but the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) is unclear about this.

Then I came across this table:
[image]

It also doesn't seem to mention what context exactly to use for a Toast?

### Edit:

Is context like a "handle to parent window" for the sub-window like Toast? or does it actually allow the `Toast.makeText` to get access to resources or something?

Why is it being used at all if the context doesn't matter?

Comment: the Activity's context. For the ui use always the activity's context

Comment: take a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/a/22295639/1462770

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [Toast.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/f4bed684c939b0f8809ef404b8609fe4ef849263/core/java/android/widget/Toast.java), I can see the `Context` is used only for:

- obtaining `Resources`
- obtaining Package Name
- `getText` which is actually same as #1

So apparently there's no difference whether it's `Activity` or `ApplicationContext`, unless those resources depend on theme (which is not the case as far as I can tell).

And no, the context passed to Toast is not a handle to parent window in any sense.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to use the activity in your case. Since you're calling from the activity itself. The activity is a Context and you're using the method on the activity to get another context (the application). It is a little unnecessary.

However in the case you're  calling a toast from somewhere else it might be a better idea to use the application, since the application will always be there while your app is active.

Answer (score 0):

You can show Toast only from UI (main thread) context. If you want show this from Service (but this is contradicts Google guidelines), you can do this way: [Show toast at current Activity from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12730675/show-toast-at-current-activity-from-service)

Comment: Google used application context: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Answer (score 0):

For toasts, which are short-lived, you can usually use whatever context you want. Typically, you would use the activity context, but application context is fine as well.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. Please review my question for an edit.